# ClassNotFoundException while Instrumentation.newApplication

Tags: android

This issue is reported by GooglePlay Console.
It can not be reproduced on my test devices. (I have over 20 devices with various Android versions).
It may happen once in over 100 users.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:628)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4964)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600 (ActivityThread.java:177)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1491)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5910)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1405)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:511)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:469)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication (Instrumentation.java:987)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:623)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9phnb.png)

Comment: Have you mentioned your application class in manifest?

Comment: Yes.  So most of users works well and I can not reproduce this issue.

Comment: Do you  have more than one application class

Comment: No. Only ONE application class.